# Control marquee behavior with buttons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, marquee

I want to be able to control marquee behavior with buttons using jQuery.

For example, I create the following buttons and when I click each of them:

```
1) Start (class=btnStart) => the marquee starts
2) Stop (class=btnStop) => the marquee stops
3) Back (class=btnBack) => the marquee move backward
4) Right (class=btnRight) => the marquee moves to right
5) Fast (class=btnFast) => the marquee moves faster
6) Slow (class=btnSlow) => the marquee moves slower

<body>
  <div>
      <marquee>Lots of contents here, scrolling right to left by default</marquee>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btnStart">Start</button>
    <button class="btnStop">Stop</button>\
  </div>
 <script>
    $(function (){

       $(".btnStop").click(function (){
          $("marquee").stop();// it does not work
        });

        $(".btnFast").click(function (){
            $("marquee").attr("scrollamount","5"); // doesnt change speed
         });
     });
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I just added what I had tried so far. To be honest, I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.start()` and `.stop()` methods works only on `javascript` objects.

`$('marquee')` returns a jquery object but you can get the **DOM** element using indexes.

`$('marquee')[0]` returns the HTML element you selected.

You can use `$('marquee')[0].start()` or `document.getElementById('marquee').start()`.

```js
let marquee=document.getElementById('marquee');
$('#btnRight').click(function(){
    marquee.setAttribute('direction','right');
    marquee.start();
});
$('#btnLeft').click(function(){
   marquee.setAttribute('direction','left');
   marquee.start();
});
$('#btnStop').click(function(){
   marquee.stop();
});
$('#btnStart').click(function(){
   marquee.start();
});
$('#btnFast').click(function(){
  marquee.setAttribute('scrollamount',30);
  marquee.start();
});
$('#btnSlow').click(function(){
  marquee.setAttribute('scrollamount',2);
  marquee.start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee id="marquee" behavior="scroll" scrollamount="10">Hello</marquee>
<button id="btnRight">Right</button>
<button id="btnLeft">Left</button>
<button id="btnStart">Start</button>
<button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
<button id="btnFast">Fast</button>
<button id="btnSlow">Slow</button>
```